# Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/png

Tags: php, mime, php-gd

I have two copies of the following code on two different rented servers:

```
<?php
$my_img = imagecreatefrompng("img.png"); 
header( "Content-type: image/png" );
imagepng( $my_img );
imagecolordeallocate( $text_color );
?>
```

When I try to run one copy I get the error in the title. When I run the other copy it works fine. What could be causing the issue?

Comment: I can add more details about the servers if necessary

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
<?php
  header("Content-Type: image/png");
  readfile("img.png");
  exit;
?>
```

There is no need to recreate image if you want just to load & show it from php file.